# How to implement "throws InterrruptedException" with ASM?

Tags: java, exception, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm using the Java ASM Byte Code Library to generate byte code for the following method body:

```
public void SearchOrSort(MyList<Integer> list) throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (this) {
        this.wait();
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
}
```

Using ASM to print the byte code of the method shown above, I got the output on the attached picture. (left column)

[image: attached picture]

The right column shows the source code I've created based on the printed byte code.

I'm struggling to implement the Label 3, 5 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Frame full" and "chop" are part of the StackMapTable attribute. In most cases, you don't have to worry about those - ASM can generate them automatically for you.

As for the label of the goto, that's just whatever label you used for the code you want to jump to. It's the same as any other control flow in that respect. Incidentally, you'll want to store your ASM labels in variables so you can reference them in later control flow instructions.

The only complication in this case is that the exception handler is autogenerated, rather than part of the code you wrote. In Java `synchronized` blocks are compiled with a secret exception handler around the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How do I implement the GOTO-Statement?

Which kind of Node is it? I cannot get it to work with an InsnNode.

Comment: @Schrello why do you use this verbose Tree API instead of the Visitor API? Do you know the ASMifier? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399605/2711488) for example.

Comment: @Schrello `JumpInsnNode` is used for *GOTO*.

Comment: @Holger It is my first time using ASM. I find the Tree API easier to use. I need to analyse the body of a method and to insert statements at specific points into a method body. I testet the tree API and the visitor api. I could insert some statements with the visitor API, but I could not manage to add them at specific points. Do you think the visitor api is somehow better?

Comment: For the code as shown in the question, the Visitor API is more concise which makes it simpler in this specific case. This doesn’t preclude the use of the Tree API. You can create a `MethodNode` and call the visitor methods on it (or use the code generated by `ASMifier`) and afterwards, read its `instructions`, to process the code as list of `AbstractInsnNode` instances.